# C# how to escape double qoutes in string for valid javascript code

Tags: c#

I'm building JS file on C#. the data is from the DB
E.g.
Label      value
lable1    "this is label 1 value"
lable2    "this is label"+ JSVar +"  value"
lable3    "this is label " 3 with error"

will create JS file containing

```
var lable1 = "this is label 1 value";
var lable2 = "this is label"+ JSVar +"&nbsp; value";
var lable3 = "this is label " 3 with error";
```

what will be the best way to add escape char to labels with error?
lable3 need to be:

    var lable3 ="this is label \" 3  with error";

**need not to escape " + var +  "  (spaces ignored) .**

Comment: please format your question

Comment: you could use a JSON encodeer.

Comment: Just put them into db like `this is label " + JSVar + "&nbsp; value` and then in your C# do `string val = string.Format("\"{0}\"", stringFromDb.Replace("\"", "\\\""));`

Comment: tnx, but i cannot edit the DB

Comment: You dont have to edit DB. Just store these strings in different way. Meaning do not add `"` at the beginning and at the end

Comment: m.rogalski - I'm not storing to the DB, i have select access to the data

Comment: Daniel A. White, how the encodeer will help?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to escape some characters, insert `@` in front of your string.

Exemple :

`string path = "C:\Windows\drivers"` will not compile.

instead of :

`string path = "C:\\Windows\\drivers"` will compile.

In C#, you can escape automatically character sequence, like this :

`string path = @"C:\Windows\driver` will compile.

In exception, if you want escape `"`, double it, so in your case :

`var lable3 = @"this is label "" 3 with error";` will escape `"` and formatted like you want.

Further information ? Go check MSDN guide about string : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx#United%20States%20(English)

Hope i helped.

Comment: tnx, but this is for JavaScript, verbatim string literal won't help